# Can "targetNamespace" is a way to create namespaces for validating XML documents

Tags: xml, schema

In an XML Schema document: Is the attribute `targetNamespace` of the `<schema>` element is a way to create a new namespace for validating XML documents that uses it?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. The targetNamespace attribute of the schema defines the namespace of the declarations (e.g. element declarations) in the schema. So if your targetNamespace is "urn:foo" and the schema declares an element bar, then that declaration will be used to validate an element of the form `<f:bar xmlns:f="urn:foo">`.

The namespace of the elements in the source document must match the namespace of the element declarations in the schema, and the namespace of the element declarations in the schema is established using `targetNamespace`.